# Bind Variables and Stored Procedures

Tags: stored-procedures

My understanding is that both parameterized queries and stored procedures help to prevent sql injection.

Do parameterized queries make it impossible to inject sql?

Do parameterized queries with very bad stored procedures make it impossible to inject sql?

Are there examples of either of the above? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, parameterized queries and stored procedures *do help* prevent SQL injection.

But saying the they make it impossible is a bit of a stretch. Injection can certainly be thwarted by using parameters AND consideration when writing queries.

But `_very bad_` queries or stored procedures can still be subject to injection.

An example would be using dynamic SQL queries in your stored procedure or query:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE [BadStoredProcedure]
   (@columnList varchar(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)       

   SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM Customers'

   EXEC (@sqlCommand)
END
```

Guess what happens if `*; TRUNCATE TABLE Customers; SELECT *` is passed into `@columnList`

Comment: "But saying the they make it impossible is a bit of a stretch. Injection is certainly thwarted by using parameters but other types of attacks may be possible"  What other types of attacks are possible?

Comment: @user2656984 - quoting text from my answer doesn't help at all but I did rephrase. Hopefully this answers your question..

Comment: I am more worried with the parameterized queries. I am aware that dynamic queries in stored procedures can be subjected to injection as per your examples :) 
My understanding of how parameterized queries work is in a sequence of prepare and execute: sequence one is a “preparequery” that is sent to the server and step two, is a “executequery” that is sent to the server with the parameters.  What do you mean by “_vary bad_” queries, any examples?

Comment: The example in my answer is subject to injection even though it parameterized. The example is for a stored procedure but the same applies to a parameterized query. That's the first that comes to mind; other situations may exist but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: thanks, so far I've failed to find a valid example of parameterization being injected/compromised. So far I've only found that it cannot be injected, see slide 50 of this video.  http://marakana.com/s/post/210/video_and_slides_sql_injection_myths_fallacies_best_practices_of_defense